# Add html word into wp_list_categories

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, categories

This is my first question, i hope a lot of this site. My friends talk very good about it.

I have a code with categorie list in 3 columns, but i want add word "Asesor " before each category.

Example:

Asesor Category 1
Asesor Category 2

This is my code:

```
<?php
// Grab the categories - top level only (depth=1)
$get_cats = wp_list_categories( 'echo=0&title_li=&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1,762,899,951' );
// Split into array items
$cat_array = explode('</li>',$get_cats);
// Amount of categories (count of items in array)
$results_total = count($cat_array);
// How many categories to show per list (round up total divided by 3)
$cats_per_list = ceil($results_total / 3);
// Counter number for tagging onto each list
$list_number = 1;
// Set the category result counter to zero
$result_number = 0;
?>

<ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-<?php echo $list_number; ?>">

<?php
foreach($cat_array as $category) {
    $result_number++;

    if($result_number % $cats_per_list == 0) {
        $list_number++;
        echo $category.'</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';
    }
    else
        echo $category.'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

I try add this in one line, but don't work:

```
echo "Asesor" .$category.'</li>';
```

Anybody can help me please? Really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories instead.
It will retrieve array of objects by default so you can just loop through and echo what you want

Comment: I'm looking suggest page but it impossible for me. I know about css, html, illustrator, photoshop, but i'm learning about php, jquery... sorry for ask. I suposse this site is for better people or only programmers. thanks anyway